# Ocaml execution of program not producing new output after some time

Tags: shell, ocaml, executable

I have 3 ocaml modules, the last one of the tree does the actual computation and uses functions defined in the other 2.

The basic idea of the program is to have a port as initial state, which contains boats, and moving those boats until we reach either a winning situation or no more moves are possible.
The actual code is not really a problem here. It is probably not very efficient, but finds a solution... except when it does not.

While the program takes a few seconds for complex situations, in some cases, when I add a bit more complexity, it takes forever to find a solutions.

When I execute the program like this:

```
$ ocamlc -o test.exe port.ml moves.ml solver.ml
$ ./test.exe > file
```

The resulting file is really huge, but its size stops increasing after some time..
It seems to me that after a while the **program stops running but without terminating, no Stackoverflow or out of memory error is thrown. The program simply does not continue the execution.** In other words, the command

```
$ ./test.exe > file
```

is still executed, but no more new lines are added to the file. If I log to the shell itself and not a file, I get the same result: no new lines keep getting added after some time.

What could this be?

The main function (that is responsible for finding a solution) uses a Depth-First-Search algorithm, and contains **a lot** of List operations, such as List.fold, List.map, List.iter, List.partition, List.filter. I was thinking that maybe these functions have problems dealing with huge lists of complex types at some moment, but again, no error is thrown, the execution just stops.

*I explained this very vaguely, but I really don't understand the problem here. I don't know whether the problem has to do with my shell (Ubuntu subsystem on windows) running out of memory, or ocaml List functions being limited at some point...  If you have any suggestions, feel free to comment*

Comment: You should provide the code, otherwise, it looks like fortune telling. One of the reasons why your code stops providing any output can be the exponential grows of some calculation's time - it still works under the hood but from the external observer point of view it looks stuck because it requires too much time to get the next step calculated etc. But there is no sense in guessing...

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can provide the code.

Comment: Update: I did not update the answer with the code as it would probably not lead to a solution. The solution is probably that the code was still running in the background, and my algorithm is so slow that it seems to have been stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug such cases you should use diagnostic utilities provided by your operating system and the OCaml infrastructure itself.

First of all, you shall look into the state of your process. You can use `top` or `htop` utilities if you're running a Unix machine. Otherwise, you can use the task manager.

If the process is running out of the physical memory, it could be swapped by the operating system. In that case, all memory operations will turn into hard drive reads and writes. Therefore, garbage collecting a heap stored in a hard drive will take some time. If this was the case, then you can use a memory profiler to identify the crux of the problem.

If the process is constantly running without a change in the memory footprint, then it looks like that you either hit a bug in your code, i.e., an infinite loop, or that some of your algorithms have exponential complexity, as Konstantin has mentioned in the comment. Use a debugging output or tracing to identify the location where the program stalled.

Finally, if your program is in the sleeping state, then it could be a deadlock. For example, if you're reading and writing to the same file, this can end up in a race condition. In general, if your program is multithreaded or operates multiple processes, there are lots of possibilities to induce a race condition.